# modify "sku" index column in Magento product sold report

Tags: magento, report, size, sku

I want to add a size column in `Magento` product sold report. Size value is the last character of `sku`. I already had `sku` column, fetching from database. But I don't know how to modify the value of `sku` to size column.
Below is my code:

```
//sku column
$this->addColumn('sku', array(
    'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Product Sku'),
    'width'     =>'250px',
    'index'     =>'sku',
    'type'      => 'text'
));
//size column
$this->addColumn('size', array(
    'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Size'),
    'width'     =>'200px',
    'index'     =>'size'
));
```

I want to set size `value = substr($sku,13,1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the value of sku to size column by using custom renderer.

Please follow this tutorial for that.

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/